# How to replace null values in map with length of key using java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, Integer>`, which has some keys and values. I want to associate all keys with the values as the key's length.
I have been able to solve this in pure java and java-8, but somehow I don't think that appending a terminal operation at the end like `.collect(Collectors.toList());` which is not required for me in my code.

My code: ( Java ) **works fine**

```
 Map<String, Integer> nameLength = new HashMap<>();
   nameLength.put("John", null);
    nameLength.put("Antony", 6);
    nameLength.put("Yassir", 6);
    nameLength.put("Karein", 6);
    nameLength.put("Smith", null);
    nameLength.put("JackeyLent",null);
    for(Entry<String, Integer> length: nameLength.entrySet()){
      if(length.getValue() == null){
        nameLength.put(length.getKey(),length.getKey().length());
      }
    }
```

**Java-8** also works fine but the terminal operation is useless, how I avoid it without using `.foreach()`.

```
nameLength.entrySet().stream().map(s->{
  if(s.getValue() == null){
    nameLength.put(s.getKey(),s.getKey().length());
  }
  return nameLength;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(nameLength);
```

Any other way in which I can do the above logic in Java-8 and above??

Comment: Why are you putting these artificial restrictions: no for statements, no `forEach`?

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also please edit your title to reflect your actual issue. _Refactoring in Java-8_ doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Whatever this is doing, it is not refactoring. You gain nothing if you randomly put lambdas in your code, this particular case there's no reason to replace a perfectly fine and working `foreach` loop with arcane constructs of streams and lambdas that barely do what original code did.

Comment: that's terrible use for `map`.. mutable operation, that doesn't return anything interesting

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to use streams then you should **avoid side effects**. Functional programming is all about pure operations where the output depends only on the input and functions have no side effects. In other words, create a new map instead of modifying the existing one.

If you do that you might as well just throw away the partially-filled-out map and recompute everything from scratch. Calling `String.length()` is cheap and it's not really worth the effort to figure out which values are null and which aren't. **Recompute all the lengths.**

```
Map<String, Integer> newMap = nameLength.keySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        name -> name,
        name -> name.length()
    ));
```

On the other hand if you just want to patch up your current map streams don't really buy you anything. I'd just modify it in place without involving streams.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: nameLength.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getValue() == null) {
    entry.setValue(entry.getKey().length());
  }
}
```

Or, as discussed above, you could simplify matters by replacing all of the lengths:

```
nameLength.replaceAll((name, __) -> name.length());
```

(`__` signifies a variable that isn't used and so [doesn't get a meaningful name](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-_-underscore-variable-name-java/).)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov My answer addresses that. It's easier to recompute everything than to do it piecemeal, so that's what the first and last snippets do. The middle one only replaces `null` values and has the ugliest code as a result.

Answer (score 3):

You almost there, just use the [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to identify the entries with null values and then use [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) to collect them into `Map` with key length as value

```
Map<String, Integer> nameLengths = nameLength.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(entry->entry.getValue()==null)
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry->entry.getKey().length()));
```

Or more simpler way you have that check in `Collectors.toMap`

```
  Map<String, Integer> nameLengths = nameLength.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry->entry.getValue() == null ? entry.getKey().length() : entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: Of all the answers I feel like you're the closest: `nameLength.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue() != null ? entry.getValue() : entry.getKey().length()));`.

Comment: OMG, thank god for downvotes, any chance of explaining why ?